# MSTeams: Carousel Card Bot.Connector.ErrorResponseException: Operation returned an invalid status

Tags: c#, botframework, microsoft-teams, azure-bot-service

Version: SDK V3 Bot Framework

Deployment : Azure

Language : C#

Adpative card Verison : 1.0

Bot Builder Version : 3.15.3

Bot Connector Version : 3.15.3 or tried even 3.20.*

Channel: MSTeams

we developed a bot which takes some input, according to it displays 9 adaptive cards in carousel format.
this was working till day before yesterday. the bot was showing carousel cards in teams channel without any errors but suddenly from today i am facing an error just when bot reply in attachment the carousel card.

The main exception which it gives is : 
Exception: Microsoft.Bot.Connector.ErrorResponseException: Operation returned an invalid status code 'BadRequest

Traced in local with ngrok
`Exception: Microsoft.Bot.Connector.ErrorResponseException: Operation returned an invalid status code 'BadRequest'
at Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Conversations.d__10.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.Bot.Connector.ConversationsExtensions.d__11.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.AlwaysSendDirect_BotToUser.d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.InputHintQueue.d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.AutoInputHint_BotToUser.d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.MapToChannelData_BotToUser.d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.LogBotToUser.d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.DialogContext.d__12.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()`

Comment: Could you please share your AdaptiveCard Json with us?

Comment: sure @Gousia-MSFT any way to direct message it?

Comment: Please send out an email to microsoftteamsdevATmicrosoftDOTcom.

Comment: @Gousia-MSFT sent

Comment: Adaptive cards inside carousel has a size limitation which is restricting your card to be displayed inside carousel. You need to make the card smaller to get it working inside carousel.

Comment: why it is working in Emulator? :o

Comment: When you send an activity to a channel, how the incoming data is handled is specific to that channel. In other words, the performance and result is channel-specific. Emulator likely has a higher card size limit than Teams.

Comment: @RizwanShaikh Max Message size differs across channels and Teams has a limit on the size of the card.

Comment: But before this it use to work even in msteams then probably they reduced the limit on incoming data recently? Teams can u confirm this?